# Get current system locale on Windows 10 in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, locale

I'm trying to get the current system locale on Windows 10 in C++.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    cout << "LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << endl;
    cout << "LC_CTYPE: " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns

```
LC_ALL: Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950
LC_CTYPE: Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950
```

I wonder if it possible to show as BCP47 language tags like `zh-TW` ?

Comment: I do not know it there are libraries, for sure it is not standard (and C has different tradition `xx_YY`). BTW in BCP47 you should use `zh-hant` for the first part (so possibly `zh-hant-TW` (`zh` is just the language, `hant` is about the writing system (*Traditional*) and `TW` about regional variant. To complicate things: Windows may not have support to all locales, and internet (so BCP47 clients) often can interpret just a subset of them.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi: The `xx_YY` tradition is Unix, not C. `"Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950"` makes perfect sense from a Windows perspective. C itself has no special rules about local names. (And C++ doesn't add them either - question is mis-tagged)

Comment: This information is unstable enough that Microsoft provides an [RSS feed](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-LCID/%5bMS-LCID%5d.rss) for the specification !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I may be seeking the wrong direction. I just start learning C and for solving certain cases, I need to get system local information and it is better to get something like `xx_YY` type.